# object is highlighted when i move orthographic camera in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, unity3d-editor

I set the orthographic camera in the unity 3d project.

The problem is that plane object is highlighted when i moved camera.

It looks like light is focused at some point.

I think this is some kind of bug.

could you tell me how can i fix this?

This is the video...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xj0TRRlLLCM

I tried following things

1. got rid of directional light <- doesn't work (why?)
2. shadow off

Please help me to solve this problem..